# embedded jetty: server html file from resource folder

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am trying to use an embedded jetty server in my application. I would like to serve an html page that only uses html and javascript. I am using maven and I put the files in `src/main/resources/html/`.

Here's my code:

```
 Server server = new Server(7498);

    URL url = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("html/");

    URI webRootUri = url .toURI();

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
            ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
    context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

    ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default",
            DefaultServlet.class);
    holderPwd.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    context.addServlet(holderPwd, "/");

    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.dump(System.err);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Problem accessing /JettyServer/index.html. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Why does it still look in /JettyServer/index.html? How do I get it to look in the resource folder?

**EDIT**

webRootUri is

```
file:/D:/Workspaces/Eclipse/Eclipse_SE/CDP/target/classes/html/
```

and inside that HTML folder, there is my index.html

Comment: Print out what the value of `webRootUri` is during your run, and add that information to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ServletContextHandler` is set at a `contextPath` of `"/"`.

That means your access to `index.html` should be at

```
http://localhost:7498/index.html
```

not

```
http://localhost:7498/JettyServer/index.html
```

Comment: I dont get that. Where does the JettyServer folder even come from? And in which project folder should I put my html files?

Comment: Got it! There was a path set as a string directly in the gui class, which I didnt see. And that path was loaded instead of my path. Thanks!